# See the code behind of an aspx page deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am wondering if there is a way to see the code behind on a .aspx page wich is already deployed on the server ?

Thanks for answering .

Comment: Are you deploying source or binaries?

Comment: Do you have access to the server file system?

Comment: The dark side is strong with this one, Hmmm...

Comment: No !!!! I just deployed my app on my IIS server , the thing is I lost 2 files during a formating, so I just wanted to take back the file from my server and then open the code behind ... But I just see the xaml when I open my file .. People close the question I didn't even finish to explain . Really .... ???

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed - I'm sometimes close-happy and still see this as a valid question. I once had to help a customer rebuild part of their website after some strange circumstances lost access to the source code. We were able to pull the .DLL and use Reflector to get back to source-code. Of course, it's not the original source, but it was good enough to work from.

Comment: What was your deployment method? I believe there are three methods, if my memory servs me correct.

Comment: Reflector was the good thing to use ! Works perfectly ! I could find the code missing on my project. Could you post It as answer I can accept ? Thanks dude !

Comment: `People close the question I didn't even finish to explain`. @Demipouce So this should teach you to write the whole explanation in question before posting it. Think about that next time. I will vote to reopen if you add more details in your question, because now it is chat in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you have access to the directory on the server.

If you're asking if it can be done client-side, then no.